List with scrollable horizontal rows - content of variable height items cropped
I have a List, that contains items where each of them is horizontal ScrolView with variable height items (depending on text line numbers). Here is the code:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(1..<12) { index in
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    LazyHStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 4) {
                        ForEach(1..<10) { innerIndex in
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)

                                let text = Array(repeating: "A", count: innerIndex * index).joined(separator: " ")
                                Text(text)
                                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                    .lineLimit(2, reservesSpace: false)
                                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                                
                                Text("Item no: \(innerIndex)")
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))

                                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                            }
                            .frame(width: 100)
                            .background(Color.yellow.opacity(0.5))
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)
    }
}

Here is how it looks:

As you can see items content is cropped. I would expect the row to grow to fit the tallest item.
How could I fix this issue?

The row cannot "grow to fit the tallest item" because it doesn't know what the tallest item is. All the items are in a lazy stack, so the row cannot know in advance what the tallest item will be. Would you like the row to expand to fit the currently visible tallest item instead? IMO, this would lead to a rather bad UX though. Can you compute the heights of the items beforehand?

See the solution to SwiftUI: Nested scroll views on opposite axis for ways to solve, the arrangement is similar.

@Sweeper It makes in case the taller views are not visible initially. But it looks that LazyHStack adjust its height only taking into consideration very first item, even though more of the are visible ate once. Take a look at last row in the image. Only the first view is "small" one and there are at least 3 other taller visible at once.
I need to stick to lazy stack due to memory footprint, so I guess the only solution would be to enforce the row height to be equal to item height with variant where there are 2 lines of the text

@Wujo Yes. Taking the height of the first view is the default behaviour. And that's why I asked whether you want it to "expand to fit the currently visible tallest item". If you do want that, I can show you how to do that. Benzy Neez's linked answer seems to also do that.
